# How to do IPv6 Subnetting (from left to right) outside nibble boundaries with LAN sizes

Tags: subnet, ipv6

Well, up to this point I'm a bit confused of how to do IPv6 Subnetting outside nibble boundaries with specific hosts numbers.

Lets say that i have a /64, and that i want to divide it in 3 subnets, 2 WAN and 1 LAN, the LAN needs to be able to handle 2000 hosts, and well, the WANS are 3 hosts wide.

The first thing that i do is to determine how many bits i require,so, for the Wans is 2 bits, and for the lan is 11 bits.

Soo, i will start from the LAN
/64+11=/75
:XXXX XXXX XXX0 0000::
So first address will be= 1000::
and last address will be= FFE0::
(from left to right)
So, between First and last address there are enough hosts for my LAN

then..
WAN1

first: FFF0::

last:  FFF8::

WAN2

first: FFFC::

last:  FFFE::

in both WAN cases, i left reserved bits at the right... so for the first i do like this
:1111 1111 111X X000::
second:
:1111 1111 1111 1XX0::

What i don't really get is then, i have a /75 for LAN1.. /77 for Wan1... /79 for WAN2, which makes no sense at all, as in both cases, that masks can handle LOTS of IP...
Then.. based on what i have seen online, is that the mask goes in the opposite way (which makes sense), so instead of a /64 + how many bits, is 128-how many bits...
In which case the bits match how many host i want to fit... but all those examples do the "subneting" from right to left.... so its possible to do as i want?

Comment: In most cases, IPv6 networks will be `/64`, else you break some IPv6 features. The exceptions are `/127` for point-to-point links, and `/128` for loopbacks.

Comment: See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/28442/8499), [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/34172/8499), etc. Please search the site.

Comment: Mathematically, bits are bits, so subnetting is the same in v6 as v4. There are just more of them, and v6 introduces some special cases. (SLAAC *requires* a /64, but you can ignore that.) Nibble boundary subnets are a convenience for your sanity. (the global pool 2000::/3 is an obvious exception)